# bc command unexpected results

Tags: test, numeric-data, bc, ip-address

I am trying to compare a decimal and it seems like `bc` is ignoring it. The OS is `CentOS release 6.9 (Final)` and bash is `bash-4.1.2-48.el6.x86_64`, below is the code

```
#!/bin/sh
i=32.39
IP_LOW_2=32.0
IP_BRD_2=32.254
TEST3=$(echo " ${i} < ${IP_BRD_2} && ${i} > ${IP_LOW_2} " | bc -l )
echo "$TEST3"
if [[ $TEST3 =  1 ]];
then
echo "Test works!"
else
echo "Test faied!"
fi
```

I think the outcome should be "Test works!" however its failing, i am tying to figure out what i am missing.

Shell execution results below:

```
sh -x testing.sh
+ i=32.39
+ IP_LOW_2=32.0
+ IP_BRD_2=32.254
++ echo ' 32.39 < 32.254 && 32.39 > 32.0 '
++ bc -l
+ TEST3=0
+ echo 0
0
+ [[ 0 = 1 ]]
+ echo 'Test faied!'
Test faied!
```

Comment: Why is that a problem?  32.39 is _not_ less than 32.254

Comment: This is actually last two octet of an IP address 10.x.32.39. I need to check if it falls in range of 32.0 and 32.254. Am i following a wrong approach here ?

Comment: Yes, this is the wrong appoach.  You can't do strict math checking like this, because "32.1" would be the same as "32.10" and "32.100".  If you want to use math inequalities then you need to compare each octet _or_ convert to three digits ("32.039" and not "32.39") so they're ordered properly.

Comment: i am not sure if i would like to convert the IP to three digits, could you suggest how each octet comparison would look like ?

Comment: In this case you know the third octet is always "32" so you can just compare the 4th octet.  Another method would be to calculate an integer value (eg 32*256+39) and compare that to the equivalent ranges (32*256+0 and 32*256+254).   Or ...  many choices.  But you can not do what you're trying, treating the IP address as a decimal.

Comment: Since this is really about IP range checking, I'm gonna flag it as a duplicate of similar questions